# Swift linking errors in trivial OS X Command Line App

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I have been using a simple command line app from within Xcode (not directly via swiftc) to test code that otherwise gives Playground fits.  After several months, and compiler updates, I cannot link seem to link a trivial and contrived snippet that extends a Swift Array.  I have code like this in an iOS app, and it compiles just fine.  I must have missed the memo at some point, but I am not sure what that was.

Here is a simple snippet (in a main.swift file) that:

```
protocol MyProtocol : SequenceType {
    func fubar()
}


extension Array : MyProtocol {
    func fubar() {}
}


println("Hello, World!")
```

That causes a multitude of linking errors like:

```
Ld /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Products/Debug/Hacks normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Redacted/development/tests/Hacks
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Intermediates/Hacks.build/Debug/Hacks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hacks.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift_static/macosx -Xlinker -force_load_swift_libs -lswiftRuntime -lc++ -framework Foundation -lcurses -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Intermediates/Hacks.build/Debug/Hacks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hacks.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Intermediates/Hacks.build/Debug/Hacks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Hacks_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Products/Debug/Hacks

duplicate symbol __TTWSaSs12SequenceTypeFS_8generateUS__USs13GeneratorType___fRQPS_FT_QS1_9Generator in:
    /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Intermediates/Hacks.build/Debug/Hacks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift_static/macosx/libswiftCore.a(Swift.o)
duplicate symbol __TTWSaSs12SequenceTypeFS_oi2tgUS__USs13GeneratorType___fMQPS_FTS1_TVSs19_UnderestimateCountT___Si in:
    /Users/Redacted/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hacks-Redacted/Build/Intermediates/Hacks.build/Debug/Hacks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift_static/macosx/libswiftCore.a(Swift.o)

... <>
```

Could there be some new linking requirements that I missed?  Seems like it must be something simple, but it is escaping me.  For all it's worth, I have duplicated this on a separate machine and am using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) - latest as of the time of posting.

---

Edited to clarify that I am attempting to build this with Xcode, not from the command line.

Comment: I get the same linking error when compiling with Xcode but not when compiling with `swiftc` in Terminal. If you don't get any help, I suggest filing a TSI with Apple and/or a Radar bug.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It will actually be my second swift bug report today, but I am actually trying to work around a third swift bug (that I will also have to file).

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. Swift definitely isn't ready for any time sensitive projects.

Comment: I filed the bug, but later found a work-around.  Create an regular Mac GUI app, then delete the assets, xib, appdelegate file, etc., edit the plist to prune the above, and create a main.swift file.  This then worked for me, using the Swift symbols.  Something is amok though with the "Command Line Tool" target though.  It must be something to do having an app bundle.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Apple claims this is now fixed in 6.3, for what it is worth - as noted in my bug filing. (thanks again)